# need to find string using from powershell

Tags: powershell

in a text something like this, I need to be able to read the project code which is unique per text file.

```
devices           : 
meta              : @{Projectcode=rvmf99999}
public_keys       : @{Key=ssh-
```

`select-string -pattern "rvmf"` picks up the whole line, I just need rvmf and the digits after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Sample input
$txt = @'
devices           : 
meta              : @{Projectcode=rvmf99999}
public_keys       : @{Key=ssh-
'@

$txt | Select-String 'rvmf\d+' | foreach { $_.Matches[0].Value } # -> 'rvmf99999'
```

- Regex `'rvmf\d+'` captures substring `'rvmf'` followed by 1 or more (`+`) digits (`\d`).
- The object output by [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) has a `.Matches` property whose first entry's `.Value` property contains what the regex captured.

  - Specifically, the output objects are of type [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo), which contains the input line (property `.Line`) as well as metadata about the source of the line and details about the regex-matching operation in the `.Matches` property.
  - Specifically, the `.Matches` property contains a collection of match-information objects; unless `-AllMatches` was passed to `Select-Object`, there will only be *one* element, however.
  - Each element of the `.Matches` collection is a [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) instance, whose `.Value` property contains what the regex captured as a whole.

---

Note: There is an **[upcoming feature](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7712)** - green-lighted, but not yet implemented as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.5 - that **will greatly simplify the command**:

```
# NOT YET IMPLEMENTED as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.5
$txt | Select-String 'rvmf\d+' -OnlyMatching # -> 'rvmf99999'
```

`-OnlyMatching` will only output the part of the line that was matched.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @andrewjung; thanks for accepting - see my update re an upcoming feature that will greatly simplify your command.